# IOS navigation bar is shifted when selected

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, xcode8

I don't even know how to explain it. Just like that all navigation bars of all tableviewcontrollers in my storyboard is messed up. Attached diagram. If I select the navigation bar the highlighted portion looks shifted down

[image]

If I select the bar button item it also get highlighted but shifted down[image]

Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Have you kept `Status bar` property of `UINavigationController` to `none`?

Comment: In the attribute inspector -> check the Top bar is (translucent navigation bar), status bar is -> Inferred.    make sure you add the navigation bar to the view controller.

Comment: did not work for me as I did not understand the suggestions. I reverted to my old version and started working with it.